# multiple similar linq queries

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a model Course, which has several many to many relationships like Age or Time.

I have this query:

```
string IDs = "1,2,3"
string[] IDList = IDs.Split(',');

return (from x in entities.Course
       where x.Ages.Where(val => IDList.Contains(val.ID.ToString())).Count() == IDList.Count()
       select x);
```

And I need to set the same query for Time and several other properties as in:

```
string IDs = "1,2,3"
string[] IDList = IDs.Split(',');

return (from x in entities.Course
       where x.Times.Where(val => IDList.Contains(val.ID.ToString())).Count() == IDList.Count()
       select x);
```

How can I make the query more dynamic so I don't have multiple similar queries?

Thanks

Comment: Is it just Linq or is it Linq to Entities? The solution would differ greatly. For Linq, just use refactor into a method. The Linq to Entities solution is at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a method that accepts an `Expression` (depeneding on your data type) and run the query that way.  You'll need to make your `Ages`, `Time`, etc implement a specific interface for it to work.

For example, assuming that you are using EF and your model is Code First using `DbSet`s, you could make this:

```
public interface IObject
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Age : IObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // The rest of the data
}

public class Time : IObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // The rest of the data
}

public class Course
{
    public virtual ICollection<Age> Ages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Time> Times { get; set; }
}

public class CourseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Course { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public IQueryable<Course> GetCourses(Expression<Func<Course, ICollection<IObject>>> exp)
    {
        var entities = new CourseContext(); 
        string IDs = "1,2,3";
        string[] IDList = IDs.Split(',');

        var c = exp.Compile();

        return entities.Course.Where(x => c.Invoke(x).Count(val => IDList.Contains(val.ID.ToString())) == IDList.Count());
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var times = GetCourses(c => (ICollection<IObject>)c.Times);
        var ages = GetCourses(c => (ICollection<IObject>)c.Ages);
    }
}
```

Comment: No prob :)  I love Expressions!  They are one of my favorite aspects of C#

Answer (score 1):

I'd make methods that return the different query results:

```
public IQuerable<Course> GetAllCourses() {
    return entities.Course;
}

public IQueryable<Course> ByAge(IQueryable<Course> source, IEnumerable<String> ages {
    return from x in source
           where x.Ages.Where(val => ages.Contains(val.ID.ToString())).Count() == IDList.Count()
           select x;
}

public IQuerable<Course> ByTimes(IQueryable<Course> source, IEnumerable<String> times) {
    return from x in source
           where x.Ages.Where(val => IDList.Contains(val.ID.ToString())).Count() == IDList.Count()
           select x;
}
```

The reason is that the method **encapsulates** your query logic - only the `where` clause is different. You can then pass in any source. You could even combine the two query filters as a chained method call:

```
var ids = new [] { "1", "2", "3" };
var coursesByAgeAndTime = ByTime(ByAge(GetAllCourses(), ids), ids);
```

Comment: well yes that is the same I achived - I was wondering if there is a way to encapsulate the whole query into 1

Comment: @user441365 The methods encapsulate the `where` logic. The `from x in source` and `select x` statements could just have easily been `source.Where(...)`.